# Нужно посчитать пройденный путь

Tags: c#

Задание: Гусеница ползет по стволу дерева, причем ползти она может только вперед или назад. Список команд размещен на форме. Высота дерева вводится с клавиатуры.
Составьте программу, позволяющую определять как общее количество пройденных гусеницей сантиметров, так и высоту, на которой она находится после выполнения каждой команды.
Кроме того, определите доползла ли она до верхушки дерева.
Примечание 1: не забудьте, что гусеница не может уползти под землю.
(*) Примечание 2: пройдя вершину  дерева гусеница начинает двигаться вниз.

Есть рабочий код, но нужно дополнить. Не могу понять как посчитать весь пройденный путь (на сколько поднялась и на сколько спустилась).

```
int val = 0;

private void Add(int addent)
{
    val = val + addent;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(val);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add(1);    
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add(2);
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add(-1);
}
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add(-2);
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = int.Parse(label1.Text);
    int b = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    label2.Text = a == b ? "Гусеница доползла до верхушки" :
    label2.Text = a > b ? "Ещё не бабочка, спускайтесь" :
    label2.Text = a < b ? "Не на вершине, но и не на земле" : label2.Text;
}
```

Comment: `как посчитать весь пройденный путь` - подумайте логически, что для этого надо? Наверно сохранить историю "передвижения", верно? Как мы это можем сделать? Ну например создать коллекцию (`List<int>`) и в методе `Add` записывать при "ходьбе" каждое значение в коллекцию.  Все, остается посчитать в коллекции нужные действия, с этим я думаю вы без труда разберетесь.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поддерживать две величины - текущую позицию и пройденный путь. Первая строчка реализует одно из примечаний.

```
private void Add(int addent)
{
   addent = (position + addend) < 0 ? -position: addent;
   position = position + addent;
   path = path + Math.Abs(addent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Судя по Вашему коду, высота дерева вводится в textBox1 - исхожу из этого

    int val = 0,    //  текущая высота
        a   = 0,    //  общее количества пройденных сантиметров
        b;          //  высота дерева

    //  кнопка button5 не нужна

    //  в label2 отображается высота, 
    //  на которой гусеница находится после выполнения каждой команды

    //  для textBox1 добавлено событие (Focus) Leave
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); //  высота дерева
    }

    private void Add(int addent)
    {
            //  проверка, что высота дерева указана
        if(textBox1.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("укажите высоту дерева");
            return;
        }
        if ((val + addent) <= 0)
            label2.Text = "Мне под землю рано";
        else if ((val + addent) == b)
        {
            a += addent;
            val += addent;
            label2.Text = "Гусеница доползла до верхушки, высота " + val.ToString();
        }
        else if ((val + addent) > b)
        {
            a   += addent;

                //  следующую строку можно записать короче, но так нагляднее
            val = b - (val + addent - b);   //  из высоты дерева вычитаются  
                                            //  метры, на которые (val + addent)
                                            //  больше высоты дерева

            label2.Text = "Ещё не бабочка, спускаюсь " + val.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            a   += addent;
            val += addent;
            label2.Text = "Не на вершине, но и не на земле, высота " + val.ToString();
        }
        label1.Text = "всего пройдено " + a.ToString();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add(1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add(2);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add(-1);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add(-2);
    }
```